How distinguish between initialData and fetched data?
I have the following query:
export const useCurrentUser = () => {
  const enabled = !isGuestUser();

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['currentUser'],
    queryFn: () => getCurrentUser(),
    gcTime: Infinity,
    initialData: enabled
      ? (jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token') as string) as User)
      : ({} as User),
    enabled,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
};

Initial Data is taken from localStorage and is very limited - I want to distinguish between initialData and the later fetched full data. How to do this?
EDIT
export const useCurrentUser = () => {
  const enabled = !isGuestUser();

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['currentUser'],
    queryFn: () => getCurrentUser(),
    gcTime: Infinity,
    initialData: enabled
      ? (jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token') as string) as User)
      : ({} as User),
    enabled,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
};

When use initialData , useQuery typescript returns User, but when use placeholderData, it is User | undefined.

From the documentation:

IMPORTANT: initialData is persisted to the cache, so it is not recommended to provide placeholder, partial or incomplete data to this option and instead use placeholderData

So you should probably just swap out your initialData for placeholderData and you can check isPlaceholderData alongside isSuccess in the useQuery result to see what state you're in.
e.g.
const { data, error, isSuccess, isError, isPlaceholderData } = useQuery({ ... });


that is the correct answer

Chat, @TkDodo but for some reason when I use placeholderData instead of initialData, typescript return undefined. See my edited answer.

that's expected because only with initialData, which is persisted to the cache, we can guarantee that data is always "there". For example, if you use placeholderData and the query errors, data will be undefined. See my blogpost here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/placeholder-and-initial-data-in-react-query

Thanks, but is there an easy way to distinguish between initialData and the data fetched? There is no isInitialData like it is with isPlaceholderData

No there isn't.. That's why you shouldn't use initialData for partial or incomplete data.
